# Extend lists within a pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series that looks like this:

```
group
A     [1,0,5,4,6,...]
B     [2,2,0,1,9,...]
C     [3,5,2,0,6,...]
```

I have similar series that I would like to add to the existing series by extending each of the lists. How can I do this?

I tried

```
for x in series:
    x.extend(series[series.index[x]])
```

but this isn't working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the series `s`

```
s = pd.Series([[1, 0], [2, 2], [4, 1]], list('ABC'), name='group')

s

A    [1, 0]
B    [2, 2]
C    [4, 1]
Name: group, dtype: object
```

You can extend each list with a similar series simply by adding them.  `pandas` will use the underlying objects `__add__` method to combine the pairwise elements.  In the case of a `list`, the `__add__` method concatenates the lists.

```
s + s

A    [1, 0, 1, 0]
B    [2, 2, 2, 2]
C    [4, 1, 4, 1]
Name: group, dtype: object
```

---

However, this would not work if the elements were `numpy.array`

```
s = pd.Series([[1, 0], [2, 2], [4, 1]], list('ABC'), name='group')
s = s.apply(np.array)
```

In this case, I'd make sure they are lists

```
s.apply(list) + s.apply(list)

A    [1, 0, 1, 0]
B    [2, 2, 2, 2]
C    [4, 1, 4, 1]
Name: group, dtype: object
```

Comment: Great, that was easy! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Solution with [`add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.add.html) function (borrowed data sample from `piRSquared`):

```
s1 = s.add(s)
print (s1)
A    [1, 0, 1, 0]
B    [2, 2, 2, 2]
C    [4, 1, 4, 1]
Name: group, dtype: object
```

EDIT:

If some index values are different, it is more complicated, because need [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) of [`union`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.union.html) of all index values and replace `NaN` by empty lists by [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
s = pd.Series([[1, 0], [2, 2], [4, 1]], list('ABC'), name='group')
s1 = pd.Series([[3, 9], [6, 4]], list('AD'), name='group')

idx = s.index.union(s1.index)
s = s.reindex(idx).combine_first(pd.Series([[]], index=idx))
s1 = s1.reindex(idx).combine_first(pd.Series([[]], index=idx))

s2 = s.add(s1)
print (s2)
A    [1, 0, 3, 9]
B          [2, 2]
C          [4, 1]
D          [6, 4]
Name: group, dtype: object
```